# Module isomorphism $M\simeq \bigoplus_{i=1}^r D/\langle p_i^{n_i}\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$M$ is a $D-module$ torsion and finitely generated. Then $M$ is cyclic if and only if $\exists p_1, \dots, p_r\in D$ not associated and $n_1,\dots, n_r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $M\simeq\bigoplus_{i=1}^r D/\langle p_i^{n_i}\rangle$.

(0) I have to point out that I find confusing the statement that the module is fintely generated and then add the condition "$M$ is cyclic". If $M$ is cyclic then it is obviosly finitely generated.

(1) Let's assume $M$ is cyclic, then it is generated by a single element. Set $M=\langle a \rangle$. This means $\bigoplus_{i=1}^r D/\langle p_i^{n_i}\rangle$ should be generated by a single element if these two sets are to be isomorphic (thinking about defining the isomorphism between the generating sets, but I don't think it is possible so I'm not going there).

How to use the torsion condition? I know it means $mr=0, m\in M$ for some $ r\in D$.

(2)  I am particularly confused on what the set $\langle p_i^{n_i}\rangle$ is as it looks like a combinations of primes generating a number.

(3) Considering the isomorphism theorem: If $M$ is finitely generated then $M\simeq \bigoplus  D/s_i$. (What are the $s_i$ elements here?). This text http://math.uchicago.edu/~womp/2007/PIDmod2007.pdf gives a construction that is similar to the isomorphism I want to show, but I don't see how being cyclic and torsion plays a part in the argument.

Comment: $D$ is a PID? Or arbitrary integral domain?

Comment: @Krish D is a PID.

Comment: Well, in that case it directly follows from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003579/isomorphism-and-cyclic-modules). Use the stracture theorem for f.g. modules over PID, and that PID implies UFD.

Comment: @Krish Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain also shows the isomorphism. Isn't the second proof (Another outline of a proof) what I am looking here?